# How to refresh a div in a Spring web app after form submission?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form that only uploads a picture, and a Controller that stores this picture in the file system.
This controller then returns a model and view which reloads the page.
Then I have an img tag which loads this picture from the file system. Likw this:

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/user}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
    <img th:src="@{/user/{pictureNumber}(pictureNumber=${Id})}"/>
</form>
```

And this is the controller that returns the picture:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{pictureNumber}")
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable(value = "pictureNumber") String userId) throws IOException {
    File directory= new File("..path"+pictureNumber);
    return Files.readAllBytes(directory);
}
```

Once I refresh the page, it then shows the loaded picture.
How do I make it that after form submission once the picture has been stored,
the div where the img tag is currently it to be reloaded so that in displays the picture without having to refresh?

Comment: Have you though about AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reload the page after the form submission:

```
 <form method="POST" th:action="@{/user}" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit(); location.reload();" />
    <img th:src="@{/user/{pictureNumber}(pictureNumber=${Id})}"/>
</form>
```